# Which Linux version to use on an old computer via USB

Tags: linux, ubuntu, usb

I have an old Dell D600(1GB Ram. 1.5Ghz) with a damaged hard drive(shows bad sectors and quits the installation process when I try installing a new OS). The optical drive as well as the USB ports still work.

I am looking for a light Linux distribution which I would be able to use on this laptop via USB.

Could someone direct me for a small Linux distribution?

Comment: Asking for materials is off-topic as per our FAQ,  the last question was changed to ask for the name of a Linux distribution instead of asking for a site.

Answer (score 1):

Smallest linux distro I've used from a LiveUSB so far was [DSL (damn small linux)](http://damnsmalllinux.org/). Think it was something lite 60 MB and should run on most machines.

Consider what you're going to use it for though, the ultra-lightweight OSs doesn't come equipped with anything but the basics (so to speak).